# Back and forward with loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android, webview

```
resultView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
                            ResultTextMaker.ASSET_URL,
                            searchResult == DEFINITION_NOT_FOUND ?
                                    ResultTextMaker.getNoResultHTML(definition.getWord(), noDefinitionStr) :
                                        ResultTextMaker.getResultHTML(),
                                        "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Hi, I have this code to display result in WebView. How to implement back and forward capability for it? I don't know what to pass to **the fifth parameter of loadDataWithBaseURL.**
My search result is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The fifth parameter is the URL you want to back into.  You are passing null so it defaults to 'about:blank'